# How to display the user friendly error messages for the  property having constraints  in grails

Tags: grails

I have a property in domain class and which is having some constraints

```
([([A-Z0-9]{2,4}-)+[0-9]{1,2}])
```

pattern. when user enter wrong pattern it displays

> Property [XXXXX] of class [XXXXX] with value [A1] does not match the required pattern [([A-Z0-9]{2,4}-)+[0-9]{1,2}].

Instead i need to display user friendly message,how to do that in grails,because am new to this grails.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To customise per domain class field you can use something like

```
className.fieldName.matches.invalid=your error message
```

explained in the [Grails Documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/matches.html)

Comment: I think you can also return a 'key' from your custom validator.  if your validation doesn't pass, return ['custom'].  Then in messages.properties you should match on className.fieldName.custom

Answer (score 3):

If you open the `i18n/messages.properties` file you'll see a property that looks something like

> default.doesnt.match.message=Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{3}] does not match the required pattern [{4}]

This property defines the default error message that is displayed when a regex constraint is violated. If you only want to change the error message that is used when this particular property's regex constraint is violated you can do that by adding a message with a more specific code.

### Update

Based on your follow-up question:

> Is any chance of doing it at domain class side or controller side

It seems that you might want to set the error message programatically. You can do this via the `errors` property that is added to a domain class after it is validated. This is an implementation of the [Errors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html) interface which provides various `rejectValue` methods that allow you to register field errors and their associated messages programatically

Comment: Is any chance of doing it at domain class side or controller side

Comment: Thanks Donal for posting this.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Default messages are in i18n files messages.properties

You'll have all the default messages. Look at the [i18n part](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/7.%20Validation.html#7.4%20Validation%20and%20Internationalization) of grails doc to see how you can specify a message

I think it's something like `className.fieldName.constraintName=message` you have to put in your `messages.properties` file under i18n directory

Comment: anything to handle it at Domain class side or controller side

Comment: this is the way to go to change the message... But, maybe there's another question in your question ? You perhaps want to know how to catch these errors and display a user friendly message... Then, when you save your domain object, use this pattern in your controller
`if(!domain.save()){if (domain.hasErrors){errors=domain.errors.collect{it.message}}}` and then your `errors` variable will contains all the error message that you can display in your view

Comment: look at the Validation paragraph in the link I provided in my answer. All you need to know is there